# Sharing links to questions on Facebook

Tags: support

On the list of possible badges, I see some that are awarded for sharing links to the site or specific questions: Announcer, Booster, and Publicist.  Presumably, these links are shared via social media.  How can I do that?  Specifically, how can I share links to specific questions on Facebook?

I swear, I've poked around trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are little icons for sharing on Twitter, Facebook and Google+ just below the question's vote tally.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But truth be told, R.M.'s Publicist badges are from questions he has been posting on reddit. I think this has to be done manually.

Comment: Strangely, I don't see these but I feel that I've seen them in the past. Certainly, I could post directly from Facebook, but I'm guessing there's some advantage to using the link buttons when available. Suffice it to say that I'm somewhat more knowledgeable about Mathematica than about Facebook. :)

Comment: They are only on the main site not here on meta

Comment: Thanks.  I see them now but I guess they're only associated with the question - not specific answers.

Comment: Correct. The URL pertains to the question, so this is sensible.

Comment: @MarkMcClure No matter where you share, if you use the URL from the `"link"` link under the question (when logged in), it embeds your user ID into the URL, which is how SE tracks the views. So you're not restricted to just the 3 options given.

Comment: @R.M OK, I get it. That subtly placed "link" actually points to the individual answer. Furthermore, the link encodes information recording whoever clicked on it allowing SE to track it. For example, if I click on the "link" under Verbeia's answer above, I generate the URL http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/372/36 You must generate a slightly different URL?

Comment: @MarkMcClure That is correct. Mine has `/5` at the end instead of `/36`,  which is my user id. Note that even though the answer links embed the ids, the badges are only for sharing links to questions...

Comment: @MarkMcClure Just to update you: My comment above is not fully correct. Sharing links to answers also count towards these badges and this was implemented sometime in January this year.